# Ruby variables managment issue

Tags: ruby, variables, pointers

I'm trying to figure out why the following codes doesn't return the same result:

**CODE 1**

```
p0 = "hello"
a = []
b = p0
1.upto(5) do |i|
  b.insert(2,"B")
  a.push b
end

a => ["heBBBBBllo", "heBBBBBllo", "heBBBBBllo", "heBBBBBllo", "heBBBBBllo"]
```

**CODE 2**

```
p0 = "hello"
a = []
b = p0
1.upto(5) do |i|
  b.insert(2,"B")
  a.push b.inspect
end

a => ["\"heBllo\"", "\"heBBllo\"", "\"heBBBllo\"", "\"heBBBBllo\"", "\"heBBBBBllo\""]
```

What I need is the Code 2's result, but I don't need the escaped char like the inspect method does.

Honestly, I really don't understand why with the inspect method works, and why in the code 1 doesn't.
It seems like that in code 1, "b" is used as a pointer, and every time it's updated, all the "linked"-b are updated.

Any clue??

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems like that in code 1, "b" is used as a pointer, and every time
>   it's updated, all the "linked"-b are updated.

Correct! In the first case, you're pushing `b` into the array five times, so the result is that `a` contains five pointers to `b`. In the second case you're pushing `b.inspect` - which is a different object from `b`.

The easiest way to fix your first example would be to call `a.push b.dup` instead, which creates a duplicate of `b` which won't be affected by future changes to `b`.

Comment: Thank you all guys, VERY usefull , finally I've understand the missing part of the puzzle ;).  Just to be curious: using b.to_s will work as the same of code 1. Why? Should .to_s method return a new string like .inspect?  thank you again!!!

Answer (score 3):

In code 1 you're pushing references to the same object. The array will contain multiple references to the same thing.

In code 2 you're pushing the `inspect` output at a distinct moment in time. The array will contain a history of `inspect`'s returned strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
p0 = "hello"
a = []
b = p0

1.upto(5) do |i|
  b.insert(2,"B")
  a.push b.clone
end
```

Comment: +1; I forgot to actually provide anything beyond an explanation :/

Answer (score 0):

'b' is a string, which is an object. When you insert a letter, it modifies the object.

In CODE 1, that same object b is being pushed into the array multiple times, and modified multiple times.

However, b.inspect returns a new string. So in CODE 2, you push a new string into the array each iteration, and that new string is a snapshot of how 'b' looked at the time.

You could use a.push b.dup instead, which creates a copy of b without changing the format.